# Do similar PCA feature importance in first few top PCs mean these variables are nearly same in the original space?

Tags: pca, feature-selection, feature-engineering, eigenvalues, importance

I am using PCA to do the data inspection. First 3 PCs explain nearly 82% of the total variance. Suppose the number of features is $n$. And I found 4 of the features have similar PCA feature importances for first 3 PCs. Say in the attached figure:
[image]
`evap_c_5`, `evap_c_7`, `w_s_5`, `w_s_7` have similar feature importance for `pc_1`, `pc_2` and `pc_3`. So can I safely conclude that those 4 variables are similar in the original space? if so, could you provide a theoretical derivation, or a literature for reference? Thanks!